# Defining recursive non-linear recurrence relation

Tags: recursion

I have a non-linear recurrence relation:

$$\epsilon_i = \sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\epsilon_{i-1}}}\epsilon_{i-1}$$
Here, $\epsilon_0\in[0,1]$, but it's really some function $f(n,p)$ for some other parameters.

I've derived by hand a lower bound $\ell_i$, and upper bound $u_i$ for $\epsilon_i$.
These are all functions of $i$ (and implicitly $\epsilon_0$), and I know that:

$$\ell_i \leq \epsilon_i\leq u_i,\quad \forall i$$

I want to use mathematica to "explore" how tight these bounds are somewhat.
Ideally, I'd:

1. Plot all three bounds (for say $i\in[1, 1000]$)
2. Put this in a manipulate call, so manipulate $n, p$.

I've worked out how to do this without the recurrence relation (so for solely the bounds).
My code for the recurrence relation seems to have issues though:

```
eps0[n_, p_] := Sqrt[(p * Log[2] + Log[p])/(2 n)]
eps[i_, n_, p_] := (Sqrt[2] * eps[i - 1, n, p])/Sqrt[1 + eps[i - 1, n, p]]
eps[0, n_, p_] := eps0[n, p]
```

This unfortunately causes a recursion depth error, even though it seems like I defined the base case $\epsilon[0, n, p] = \epsilon_0[n, p]$, like I was supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

No need to define `eps0`:

```
Clear[eps]
eps[0, n_, p_] := Sqrt[(p*Log[2] + Log[p])/(2 n)]
eps[i_, n_, p_] := (Sqrt[2]*eps[i - 1, n, p])/Sqrt[1 + eps[i - 1, n, p]]
```

[image]

You may want to introduce [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), and/or to force `eps` to evaluate on numeric inputs only. I leave this to you, but feel free to ask for more details if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you have not used [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html). Use

```
ClearAll[eps];
eps0[n_, p_] := Sqrt[(p*Log[2] + Log[p])/(2 n)];
eps[i_, n_, p_] := eps[i, n, p] = 
     (Sqrt[2]*eps[i - 1, n, p])/Sqrt[1 + eps[i - 1, n, p]];
eps[0, n_, p_] := eps0[n, p];
```

Then you can explore the recursion with something like

```
DiscretePlot[eps[n, .5, 1.1], {n, 300}]
```

It is **important** to use `ClearAll[eps]` because the **memoization** will save function values, and if you ever change the definition of `eps[]` then the saved values will probably be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are running this backwards. Maybe use `FixedPointList[ ]` and start from $\epsilon_{0}$? This code works.

```
eps0[n_, p_] := Sqrt[(p*Log[2] + Log[p])/(2 n)];

Manipulate[
         ListPlot@FixedPointList[# Sqrt[2./(1 + #)] &, eps0[n, p], 1000], 
         {n, 1, 100, 1}, 
         {p, 1, 10}
         ]
```

I don't know what the bounds are on your parameters. For the bounds I set, the plot updates as fast as you move the sliders. The fixed point is limited to 1000 iterations, but seems to always stop at about 130.

[image]